# Locate a control and hide elements

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of Div's on the page

```
<div id="MainDiv"><div>sometext</div>
<div>sometext</div>
<div>Page 1</div>
<div>Page 1</div>
<div>Page 1</div>
<div id="Placeholder1"></div>
<div>othertext</div>
<div>othertext</div>
<div>Page 2</div>
<div>Page 2</div><div>
```

How do I hide all child Div's of 'MainDiv' that fall after the div 'Placeholder1'.

Also on a long page, is it possible that once the page loads, the browsers scrolls directly to the Placeholder? Is this possible and is there a cross-browser solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding all elements after Placeholder1,

```
$("#Placeholder1").nextAll('div').hide();
```

and for scrolling

```
$(document).scrollTop($("#Placeholder1").offset().top)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Placeholder1 ~ div').hide()
```

OR

```
$('#Placeholder1').nextAll('div').hide()
```

[ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) is a plugin that might help you with the second part of your question.

Comment: thanks bobby..is it possible to hide all controls inside 'MainDiv' after Placeholder1..so not only div but all the controls?

Answer (score 0):

To auto-scroll to the element just use a hash link (this works in all browsers), for example:

```
myPage.html#Placeholder1
```

To hide the divs after it, just just [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), like this:

```
$("#Placeholder1").nextAll("div").hide();
```

Comment: Doesn't the ScrollTop as suggested by Chinmayee work cross browser?

Comment: @AdamFo - It does, but there's really no need for it, it's already built-into the browsers (for a *very* long time) :)

Comment: Ok but what I do not get is how do I programmatically do it using the myPage.html#Placeholder1 using jquery syntax? On a page load, the scroll has to go down to Placeholder1 and this control has nothing inside it. It is just a placeholder so not visible to the user

Comment: @AdamFo - You don't need JavaScript at all, just link to the page with a `#Placeholder1` on the end and it'll scroll down.  If you *have* to programmatically do it, just use `location.hash = "Placeholder1";`